# Why does my question have so few votes?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question that attracted only a single upvote, and a single answer. Is there something wrong with my question that would help it to gain more attention? I want to ask questions that are both good questions for this site, attract good answers, and help me with my cookings problems.

This is the question: *[Will my results differ when using a sourdough starter vs poolish for pizza dough?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/53442/will-my-results-differ-when-using-a-sourdough-starter-vs-poolish-for-pizza-dough)*

Comment: I would prefer for this question to be deleted, and instead keep the following question open: http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/is-this-a-good-question-for-seasoned-advice